# There was a exception after added transactional (readOnly = false) in Hibernate 5 and Spring 4 MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am doing spring + hibernate application. 
But There was a  exception  after added transactional (readOnly = false) in CatDaoImpl.java
When I run the application on tomcat server I am getting some exceptions.

CatDaoImpl.java

```
package demo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import demo.entity.Cat;
import tw.com.owl.core.hibemate.persistence.HibernatePersistenceSupport;

@Repository("catDao")
public class CatDaoImpl extends HibernatePersistenceSupport implements CatDao {  

  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly = false)  <----Add this
  public void save(Cat cat) {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(cat);
  }

}
```

HibernatePersistenceSupport.java

```
package tw.com.owl.core.hibemate.persistence;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * HibernatePersistenceSupport
 * 
 */
 @Repository("hibernatePersistenceSupport")
public abstract class HibernatePersistenceSupport {

  @Resource(name = "jdbcTemplate")
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  private HibernateDaoSupport hibernateDaoSupport = new HibernateDaoSupport() {
  };

  public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return hibernateDaoSupport.getSessionFactory();
  }

  @Resource(name = "hibernate_sessionFactory")
  public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    hibernateDaoSupport.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
  }

  public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
    return hibernateDaoSupport.getHibernateTemplate();
  }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup><!-- -->
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pocket.*,demo.*,test" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
      <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />



 <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix">
       <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
       <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="2" />
  </bean>


</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="hibernate.xml" />

    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="demo,test,com.pocket.business" scoped-proxy="targetClass" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/conf/application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- dataSource jdbc -->    
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>${database.driverClass}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>${database.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${database.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${database.password}</value>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="password"> <ref local="decodedPassword"/> </property> -->
        <property name="maxActive">
            <value>100</value>
        </property>
        <property name="testOnBorrow">
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="validationQuery">
      <value>select 1</value>
    </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

hibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

  <bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">import.sql</prop>
                  <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop> <!-- Validation modes: AUTO, CALLBACK, NONE -->  
                  <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">false</prop>    <!-- true|false -->    
        </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernate_transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"></tx:annotation-driven>

  <bean id="hibernate_sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"/>
     <property name="packagesToScan">  
        <list>
            <value>demo.*</value>     
        </list>  
    </property> 

  </bean>



  <!-- hiberante Trasaction -->
  <bean id="hibernate_transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate_sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Tomcat 8 exception

```
Tue Apr 25 17:31:53 CST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Tue Apr 25 17:31:53 CST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
04 25, 2017 5:31:53 下午 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
info: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@196a19ee] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext refresh
warm: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'c3_PersistData': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'catDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catDao' defined in file [/Users/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/springmvc/WEB-INF/classes/demo/dao/CatDaoImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
error: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'c3_PersistData': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'catDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catDao' defined in file [/Users/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/springmvc/WEB-INF/classes/demo/dao/CatDaoImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catDao' defined in file [/Users/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/springmvc/WEB-INF/classes/demo/dao/CatDaoImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2541)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.sortAdvisors(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder$PartialComparable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 48 more

04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
error: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'c3_PersistData': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'catDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catDao' defined in file [/Users/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/springmvc/WEB-INF/classes/demo/dao/CatDaoImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'catDao' defined in file [/Users/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/springmvc/WEB-INF/classes/demo/dao/CatDaoImpl.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/util/PartialOrder$PartialComparable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2541)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.sortAdvisors(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder$PartialComparable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 48 more

04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
error: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
error: Context [/springmvc] startup failed due to previous errors
04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
info: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
warm: The web application [springmvc] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
warm: The web application [springmvc] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
info: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
info: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
04 25, 2017 5:31:55 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
info: Server startup in 8936 ms
```

Comment: it is NoClassDefFoundError.  org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder$PartialComparable is not present on run time. confirm if jar for this class is present there.

Comment: @AkshayKhopkar  Thanks you!! After adding jar it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is NoClassDefFoundError. org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder$PartialComparable is not present on run time. confirm if jar for this class is present there.